# I wanna change DIV area When Date changed

Tags: javascript, date, jquery-animate

actually, I'm trying to change DIV Content when Date changed..

I can change Div content through animate function().

But I can't apply it as Date changed...T.T

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
   <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
 .stick{
 background :cyan;
 width:0px; height:20px 
 }
```

```
<body>
<div class="stick"></div> 
</body>

<script>
 var d = new Date(); 
 //d.getDate().. what function should I use?
  $(".stick").animate({width:"+=10"}); //here is ok   
  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question.

Comment: You should post your code in text instead of image, it's much more simple to read. And format it by using the `{}` button

Answer (score 1):

**Try this its working :**

**HTML :**

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
<div class="stick"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
var d = $('#date').change(function(){   
$(".stick").animate({width:"+=10"}); 
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.stick{ 
background :cyan; width:0px; height:20px 
}
```

**Jsfiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/w5ur8w2u/

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking after is something like a digital clock, then you may need `setInterval`.

Comment: I just want to show div area and Time operate internally